# Interpolation of missing values in 3D data-array in python

Tags: python, 3d, interpolation, nan, python-xarray

I am struggeling with the following issue for quite some time and could not find a working solution yet.

I want to interpolate missing values (nan) in my data-array [in Python]. The array has the dimension lon, lat, time – it is a raster dataset over time.

Unfortunately there are some timesteps where all values are missing and where an interpolation with lon and lat (2D) is not possible. This is why I came up with the idea to interpolate over the time axis.  I want the missing value of one timesteps gets interpolated with the value of the timestep before and after at the exact same pixel.

Do you have any ideas how to do that?

My current attempt was:

" def arr_interp(array):
arrN=np.array(array,copy=False)
arrN[np.isnan(arrN)]=interpolate.interp2d(my_array.lat, my_array.lon, my_array.time, fill_value="nan")

arr_interp(my_array)"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the NaN data may form blocks, where you cannot interpolate from the neighbors.

A solution is to do [Gauss Seidel interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) solving the [Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation), (which creates data minimizing the curvature of the function).

This code finds the NaN values and does a 3D interpolation. I do not have access to your data, so it is done over synthetic data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# create data
print("Creating data...")
size = 10  # 3D matrix of size: size³
# create x,y,z grid
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, size), np.arange(
    0, size), np.arange(0, size))


def f(x, y, z):
    """function to create synthetic data"""
    return np.sin((x+y+z)/2)


data = np.zeros((size, size, size))
data[x, y, z] = f(x, y, z)

# create corrupted data
sizeCorruptedData = int(data.size*.2)  # 20% of data is corrupted
# create random x,y,z index for NaN values
xc, yc, zc = np.random.randint(0, size, (3, sizeCorruptedData))

corruptedData = data.copy()
corruptedData[xc, yc, zc] = np.nan

# Interpolate on NaN values
print("Interpolating...")

# get index of nan in corrupted data
nanIndex = np.isnan(corruptedData).nonzero()

interpolatedData = data.copy()
# make an initial guess for the interpolated data using the mean of the non NaN values
interpolatedData[nanIndex] = np.nanmean(corruptedData)


def sign(x):
    """returns the sign of the neighbor to be averaged for boundary elements"""
    if x == 0:
        return [1, 1]
    elif x == size-1:
        return [-1, -1]
    else:
        return [-1, 1]

#calculate kernels for the averages on boundaries/non boundary elements
for i in range(len(nanIndex)):
    nanIndex = *nanIndex, np.array([sign(x) for x in nanIndex[i]])

# gauss seidel iteration to interpolate Nan values with neighbors
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method
for _ in range(100):
    for x, y, z, dx, dy, dz in zip(*nanIndex):
        interpolatedData[x, y, z] = (
            (interpolatedData[x+dx[0], y, z] + interpolatedData[x+dx[1], y, z] +
             interpolatedData[x, y+dy[0], z] + interpolatedData[x, y+dy[1], z] +
             interpolatedData[x, y, z+dz[0]] + interpolatedData[x, y, z+dz[1]]) / 6)


# plot results
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axarr[0, 0].imshow(data[:, :, 1])
axarr[0, 0].title.set_text('Original Data')
axarr[0, 1].imshow(corruptedData[:, :, 1])
axarr[0, 1].title.set_text('Corrupted Data')
axarr[1, 0].imshow(interpolatedData[:, :, 1])
axarr[1, 0].title.set_text('Fixed Data')
axarr[1, 1].imshow(data[:, :, 1]-interpolatedData[:, :, 1])
axarr[1, 1].title.set_text('Error = Original-Fixed')
f.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I use your method (with an array of the shape 246 x 93 x114) I get the an index error at the Gauss-Seidl Interpolation step --> IndexError: index 114 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 114. Can it be that the code is only working when the dimension lengh is the same?

Comment: And can you also explain why the lengh you are interpolating over is 100 (Gauss Seidl Interpolation --> ("is for _ in range(100)"). Because of the 10x10 axis?

Comment: Another uncertainty came up: You made a meshgrid of which you created the array. I have an xarray and convert it into an numpy array. As I have to state the dimensions I use: #name dimensions of nan values 

xc= nanIndex[0] # time 
yc= nanIndex[1] # lat
zc= nanIndex[2] # lon 

Is this right? or is there a differerence to the created meshgrid dimensions?  Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I dont yet have enough reputation to comment however to add to @Colim's answer replacing the for loop with a vectorised version will increase performance significantly

```py
for _ in tqdm(range(100)):
    x, y, z, dx, dy, dz = nanIndex
    interpolatedData[x, y, z] = (
            (interpolatedData[x+dx[:,0], y, z] + interpolatedData[x+dx[:,1], y, z] +
             interpolatedData[x, y+dy[:,0], z] + interpolatedData[x, y+dy[:,1], z] +
             interpolatedData[x, y, z+dz[:,0]] + interpolatedData[x, y, z+dz[:,1]]) / 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified @Colim's answer to extend to non cube shaped arrays. This seems to work for me.

```
def GS_interp(array_3d):
    # dimensions of input
    size = array_3d.shape

    # get index of nan in corrupted data
    nanIndex = np.isnan(array_3d).nonzero()

    interpolatedData = array_3d.copy()

    # make an initial guess for the interpolated data using the mean of the non NaN values
    interpolatedData[nanIndex] = np.nanmean(array_3d)

    def sign(index, max_index):
        # pass additional max_index to this func as this is now a variable
        if index == 0:
            return [1, 0]
        elif index == max_index - 1:
            return [-1, 0]
        else:
            return [-1, 1]

    # calculate the sign for each dimension separately
    nanIndexX, nanIndexY, nanIndexZ = nanIndex[0], nanIndex[1], nanIndex[2]
    signsX = np.array([sign(x, size[0]) for x in nanIndexX])
    signsY = np.array([sign(y, size[1]) for y in nanIndexY])
    signsZ = np.array([sign(z, size[2]) for z in nanIndexZ])
            
    for _ in range(100):
        for i in range(len(nanIndexX)):
            x, y, z = nanIndexX[i], nanIndexY[i], nanIndexZ[i]
            dx, dy, dz = signsX[i], signsY[i], signsZ[i]

            neighbors = []
            if dx[0] != 0:  # can average with the previous x neighbor
                neighbors.append(interpolatedData[np.clip(x + dx[0], 0, size[0] - 1), y, z])
            if dx[1] != 0:  # can average with the next x neighbor
                neighbors.append(interpolatedData[np.clip(x + dx[1], 0, size[0] - 1), y, z])

            if dy[0] != 0:
                neighbors.append(interpolatedData[x, np.clip(y + dy[0], 0, size[1] - 1), z])
            if dy[1] != 0:
                neighbors.append(interpolatedData[x, np.clip(y + dy[1], 0, size[1] - 1), z])

            if dz[0] != 0:
                neighbors.append(interpolatedData[x, y, np.clip(z + dz[0], 0, size[2] - 1)])
            if dz[1] != 0:
                neighbors.append(interpolatedData[x, y, np.clip(z + dz[1], 0, size[2] - 1)])

            # average the neighbors to interpolate the NaN value
            interpolatedData[x, y, z] = np.nanmean(neighbors)
    
    return interpolatedData
```

It is quite a straightforward modification, and there is probably a more efficent way to write it. But hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. The question didn't provide an [mre]. If you are to continue this, you need to agree on some MRE and validate your methods with it. **Provided this sticks strictly to the question, otherwise this needs to be sent to a different post.**